# ggplot sum and means of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I am trying to create two graphs where the x-axis of both will be the Filename (see small example of data organization below).

For an individual Filename, there will be multiple occurrences of a particular phylum - each with a different M1 value.

```
    Phylum      M1   Filename
Acidobacteria 55.75 4461130.3
Acidobacteria 57.08 4461130.3
Acidobacteria 54.61 4461125.3
Acidobacteria 53.49 4461145.3
Acidobacteria 57.99 4461145.3
Acidobacteria 53.05 4461161.3
Acidobacteria 51.03 4461161.3
Acidobacteria 50.20 4461227.3
Acidobacteria 51.88 4461227.3
```

Plot 1: x-axis is the Filename instances. y-axis is the number of times each phylum occurs for each Filename (e.g. w/ Acidobacteria = 2 for Filename 4461145.3).

Plot 2: x-axis is the Filename instances. y-axis is the mean value of M1 for each phylum that occurs for each Filename (e.g. w/ Acidobacteria (n=2), mean_M1 = 55.74 for Filename 4461145.3).

The points on the graph should be colored by Phylum and for each Filename, the sum and mean values for each phylum should be in a vertical line. For the example given, there is only one Phylum name which makes the request a bit trivial, but there are over 30 unique Phylum in my dataset.

I can plot the raw M1 values for each phylum (it colors properly too) by filename, but I cannot quite figure out the nomenclature for getting the sum and the mean values of M1. I was trying to use lapply, but I cannot figure out how to incorporate it with ggplot.

```
FN = env.txt
myDF = read.csv(FN, header=TRUE, sep=' ')

f <- qplot(Filename, M1, data=myDF)
f + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Phylum))) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

e <- qplot(Filename, mean(M1), data=myDF)
e + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Phylum))) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

g <- ggplot(myDF, aes(Filename, M1))
g + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Phylum))) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(Filename, mean(M1)))
p + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ Phylum) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

q <- qplot(Filename, M1, data=myDF, fun.y='mean')
q + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ Phylum) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Images of attempts can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXZwW.jpg The first one is roughly the right idea, but instead of having all the values of M1, I would like the mean. I have not attempted the summation problem.

Assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a dataframe with the M1 means and sums, called `myDF.agg`, using `plyr`?

```
library(plyr)
FN = env.txt
myDF = read.csv(FN, header=TRUE, sep=' ')
myDF.agg = ddply(myDF, .(Filename, Phylum), summarize, mean_M1 = mean(M1), sum_M1 = sum(M1))
e.mean <- qplot(Filename, mean_M1, data=myDF.agg)
e.mean + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Phylum))) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,     hjust=1))

e.sum <- qplot(Filename, sum_M1, data=myDF.agg)
e.sum + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Phylum))) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,     hjust=1))
```